# Transactional/Commercial classification - Custom Unsubscribe page/link

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email

According to the SFMC knowledge base, the main difference between Transactional and Commercial emails in SFMC:
" For commercial messages, we check for the presence of an unsubscribe link. [...] For transactional messages, we do not check for the presence of an unsubscribe." 
Which Unsubscribe link is checked by SFMC for defining a Transactional/Commercial email ? Is it the "standard" Unsubscribe link from SFMC : %%unsub_center_url%% ?

If we use a custom Cloud Page as Unsubscribe page/link, can you confirm that SFMC won't be able to check if the message is OK with Transactional or Commercial rules ? If yes, in that case, is the Transactional/Commercial classification finally irrelevant and useless?

Answer (score 1):

The transactional classification will still make sense. It will allow you to bypass any *Unsubscribed* status in All Subscribers list, which would have prevented a commercial email from being sent out:

> If you select a Transactional classification, a checkbox labeled Honor
>   source and publication list level opt outs appears. Transactional
>   sends do not check these lists for subscription status during a send
>   by default. However, choosing this box excludes all subscribers who
>   opted out of sends, and clicked Spam or unsubscribe in email clients.

As described in [this help article.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_send_classification.htm&type=5)

Comment: OK, but if the Unsubscribe link is a Custom link (that doesn't update All Subscribers with the Unsubscribe status, but that updates an Optin field on a Data Extension) then I guess that the Transactional classification won't make a lot of sense ?

Comment: If this indeed is the case, and you don't trigger an Unsubscribe event on SFMC, the status in All Subscribers will remain active, however they still might have provided spam complaints - which would also prevent Commercial classifications from reaching them.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the unsub center brand tag changed by contacting support. If you use a custom page, then you can get the checks to still work with the %%unsub_center_url%% by letting them know the custom url to add when you use the personalisation string.

Comment: Instead of setting the custom url in unsub center brand tag (which will be a nightmare to maintain), it is possible to request support to disable CAN-SPAM verification of emails, allowing you to customise the footer entirely- along with custom preference centre url

Comment: Yeah, this what we asked for, so the presence of the SFMC standard Unsubscribe link %%unsub_center_url%% is no more verified. I just wanted to understand if the CAN SPAM classification would still make sense in that case.